# What's the significance of notify() statement while using wait() in a threading programme

Tags: java, multithreading

```
public class ThreadA {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ThreadB threadB = new ThreadB();
        threadB.start();
        synchronized (threadB) {
            try {
                threadB.wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        System.out.println("the total is ====>"+threadB.total);

    }
}
```

```
class ThreadB extends Thread
{
    int total;
    public void run(){
        synchronized (this) {
            for(int i =0; i<5;i++)
            {
                System.out.println("lets add===>"+i);
                total+= i;
            }
            notify(); // line no.31
            System.out.println("after notify but within lock");

        }
        System.out.println("after notify but outside lock");

    }
}
```

```
output : 
lets add===>0
lets add===>1
lets add===>2
lets add===>3
lets add===>4
after notify but within lock
the total is ====>10
after notify but outside lock
```

My question : shouldn't the control go back to the "Main" thread immediately after line no.31. Ideally shouldn't it print -
"the total is ====>10" immediately after "lets add===>4"?

Why it is that it executes all the statements within the synchronized block irrespective of the notify() statement in line no.31?

Comment: Locking, notifying(), and waiting() on a `Thread` instance?  Bad idea.  The `Thread` class does all of those things for its own reason.  You don't want the code that you write to mess with that.  Rule of thumb: your classes should only synchronize on instances that are accessed via `private final` fields unless you have a very good reason to do otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

the order of last couple of lines will not be same always. it depends on the how the threads are being scheduled and there is no guarantee, based on the code you have. the moment you have executed `notify` the `wait` is over, so any thread can run in any order. however `after notify but within lock` is within lock so even if main thread is executed its locked and can't do anything

Answer (score 0):

> My question : shouldn't the control go back to the "Main" thread immediately after line no.31.

You're asking for the impossible. The thread that called `notify` is still in a synchronized block. Once the other thread finishes waiting, it's back in the synchronized block. So what you are asking for would require two threads to be in synchronized blocks on the same object at once, which is precisely what such blocks prohibit.

```
    synchronized (threadB) {
        try {
            threadB.wait();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    System.out.println("the total is ====>"+threadB.total);
```

So this code does this:

1. Enter synchronized block.
2. Call `wait`.
3. Exit synchronized block.
4. Print the total.

Notice:

1. We can't exit the synchronized block unless we're in the synchronized block; and
2. We can't exit the synchronized block until we return from `wait`; thus
3. We can't go from `wait` to printing the total without being in the synchronized block, thus we cannot do so while another thread remains in the synchronized block or else there would be two threads in the synchronized block at once.

Now look at this code:

```
        notify(); // line no.31
        System.out.println("after notify but within lock");
    } // exit synchronized block
```

So any thread that notifies another thread does not leave its synchronized block until after it prints. Thus the notified thread cannot exit its synchronized block until after the print either.